# Remove the rows from pandas dataframe, that has sentences longer than certain word length

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I want to remove the rows from the pandas dataframe, that contains the strings from a particular column whose length is greater than the desired length.

For example:

Input frame:

```
X    Y
0    Hi how are you.
1    An apple
2    glass of water
3    I like to watch movie
```

Now, say I want to remove the rows which has the string of words with length greater than or equal to 4 from the dataframe.

The desired output frame must be:

```
X    Y
1    An apple
2    glass of water
```

Row with value 0,3 in column 'X' is removed as the number of words in column 0 is 4 and column 3 is 5 respectively.

Comment: @anky_91 `greater than or equal to 4`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First split values by whitespace, get number of rows by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and check by inverted condition `>=` to `<` with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Y'].str.split().str.len().lt(4)]
#alternative with inverted mask by ~
#df = df[~df['Y'].str.split().str.len().ge(4)]
print (df)
   X               Y
1  1        An apple
2  2  glass of water
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the spaces:

```
df[df.Y.str.count('\s+').lt(3)]

   X               Y
1  1        An apple
2  2  glass of water
```