# Remove rows from pandas dataframe that has column containing string where words have greater than a certain length

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, max

I have this dataframe

```
qid question_stemmed    target  question_length total_words
443216  56da6b6875d686b48fde    mathfracint1x53x5 tantanboxedint1x01x2 sumvarp...   1   589 40
163583  1ffca149bd0a19cd714c    mathoverbracesumvartheta8infty vecfracsumkappa...   1   498 31
522266  663c7523d48f5ee66a3e    star trek 2013 ?make warping look quite bit li...   0   449 66
341312  42dc38e62f0bdebfa6b6    answer mathfrac4222262mid 5501int846fracomega2...   0   334 11
149952  1d53c9c017999b4f77e2    8430397824532987451912384179815150754023741609...   0   241 3
```

I am looking to remove rows like above where `question_stemmed` column in this case has a string of multiple words where word length exceeds a certain character length (Ex: 15 characters)

How do i achieve the above?
I found another stackoverflow link - [Remove the rows from pandas dataframe, that has sentences longer than certain word length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563681/remove-the-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-that-has-sentences-longer-than-certain-wo)

but that essentially removes rows where number of words is greater than a certain limit, but my objective is different. Appreciate any help here!

Comment: would `df[~df['question_stemmed'].str.len() > 15]` work ? you just need to measure the entire string right?

Comment: i suspect this calculates the length of the whole string under the column and returns all rows where length < = 15. In my case returned null because all rows have length greater than 15

Comment: I'm not conceptually following  you - could you add a few rows of input and output data?

Comment: sure, i have updated my question with the input data (you can see the question_text column in the dataframe). The output i am getting is no rows returned. Just column names 

`qid question_stemmed target question_length total_words`

Comment: Answer posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918301/return-rows-w-string-content-that-dont-have-words-exceeding-a-certain-max-leng?noredirect=1#comment111266856_62918301