# Return rows w/ string content that don't have words exceeding a certain max length while retaining and filtering out words w/ certain content

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

Here is my dataframe

**Input**

```
        qid                     question_stemmed    target  question_length total_words
443216  56da6b6875d686b48fde    mathfracint1x53x5 tantanboxedint1x01x2 sumvarp...   1   589 40
163583  1ffca149bd0a19cd714c    mathoverbracesumvartheta8infty vecfracsumkappa...   1   498 31
522266  663c7523d48f5ee66a3e    httpgooglecom check out the content of the www..    0   449 66
522379  756678d3d48f5ee66a3e    mark had a great day he plans to go fishing with.   0   310 23
```

I am using the following logic to only return records from the df whose question_text column has

- any word whose length shouldn't exceed 15 characters (note: not string
  length) (using negation)
- any word that shouldn't contain numeric values while above condition is true
  (using negation)
- while making sure words with http or www values are retained (while above 2 conditions are still true)

`df = df[(~df['question_stemmed'].str.len() > 15) & (~df['question_stemmed'].str.contains(r'[0-9]')) & (df.question_stemmed.str.match('^[^\http]*$'))]`

Getting error
`error: bad escape \h at position 3`

**Expected output**

```
        qid                     question_stemmed     target    question_length  total_words
522266  663c7523d48f5ee66a3e    httpgooglecom check out the content of the www..    0   449 66
522379  756678d3d48f5ee66a3e    mark had a great day he plans to go fishing with.   0   310 23
```

Also, wondering if the logic above will work or not to satisfy all 3 conditions
Appreciate any help

Comment: The error is due to `\h` escape, there is no such a string escape sequence. Could you please clarify? So, you want to ignore the first two checks for URLs? Could you provide expected output for the above df?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - i have added expected output. Hope that makes it clear. I want to basically filter out all rows that have words with length > 15 and that have number content in those words (Ex:mathfracint1x53x5)  while making sure i don't filter out words that have http or www values in the string content

Comment: Do you really want to analyze the `question_stemmed` column with values like `56da6b6875d686b48fde`?

Comment: that is just qid. Main thing to analyze is the `question_stemmed' column (Pardon my mis-format :/). Let me try to change it to make it more readable :D

Comment: @Shalin why does the row with `"httpgooglecom check out the content of the www"` gets filter since it contains `'http'`?

Comment: Try `df = df[~df['question_stemmed'].str.contains(r'(?<!\S)(?!\S*(?:http|www\.))\S{15}')]`

Comment: @MrNobody33 - i had initially removed punctuations hence www.google.com got replaced by wwwgooglecom, so i want to retain this for future reference; i don't classify this as junk content.

Comment: awesome thanks @WiktorStribiżew. It works. regex is a game changer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
df = df[~df['question_stemmed'].str.contains(r'(?<!\S)(?!\S*(?:http|www\.))\S{15}')]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XYRIqw/1/)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - whitespace or start of string should come immediately before the current location
- `(?!\S*(?:http|www\.))` - no 0 or more non-whitespace chars followed with `http` or `www.` substrings allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `\S{15}` - fifteen non-whitespace chars.